# Angular2: insert component into a certain position

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

i've this template file for my component:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #scheduleForm="ngForm" *ngIf="schedule">
    <div #placeholder></div>

</form>
```

and i would to add two component into placeholder div. 
This is my code for adding components inside ngOnInit:

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ExternalComponent);
    let ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
     ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Where ExternalComponent is the component i would put inside.
With this code, ExternalComponents are added at the end of template (after login form). How can i put it inside #placeholder div?

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9035

If you want your dynamic component to be placed inside `div` add a `template` or `ng-container`(they are not stamped to the DOM) inside `div` and use it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div>
        <ng-container #placeholder></ng-container>
      </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy { 
  @ViewChild('placeholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) placeholderContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    let compRef = this.placeholderContainer.createComponent(factory);
    this.compRef = compRef;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.compRef.destroy();
  }
}
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HKK7biB4ZDNr1Ydsg7g9?p=preview)